# how can we compare two lists which are in two different files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and I'm using python 2.7.6. In my program I've to compare two lists which are in two different files like the ones below:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] #this list is in file 'a.txt'
list2=[2,4,6,8,10] #this list in file 'b.txt"
diff = difflib.ndiff(open('a.txt').readlines(),open('b.txt').readlines())
```

I used `difflib` but I'm not getting the correct output

How do I compare these two list and print out the differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get values which are only in one list you can use set difference operation.

```
>>> list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> list2=[2,4,6,8,10]
>>> set(list1) - set(list2)
set([1, 3, 9, 5, 7])
```

How to read the lists from file is another question. It depends on format of the files, what delimiter you use. Assuming that you have a file with one item per line:

```
data1 = [int(line.strip()) for line in open("a.txt", 'r')]
data2 = [int(line.strip()) for line in open("b.txt", 'r')]
res = list((set(data1) - set(data2)).union(set(data2) - set(data1)))
```

You pointed in the comment that file contains one line with values separated by commas, so:

```
data1 = open("a.txt", 'r').readline().strip().split(',')
data2 = open("b.txt", 'r').readline().strip().split(',')
res = list((set(data1) - set(data2)).union(set(data2) - set(data1)))
```

Comment: yeah thankx. but that was done at command line. my problem was i've the lists in two different files

Comment: I see but I dont know the format of your file. I assume that each item in line, right?

Comment: actually i commentd it. ok they are in text files

Comment: the files are text files and the nubers are separated by commas

Comment: thank you very much the code works. but how do i access the set like a list it's saying the set can't be accessible

Comment: If you must print the whole differences you will need to union the differences; res = (set(data1) - set(data2)).union(set(data2) - set(data1))

Comment: thank you for the comment xecgr. can we convert the set type to a list type by simple data type conversion, because i need to access the individual elements of the set

Comment: I fixed it in the answer. Thank you @xecgr

Comment: @user3847509 I added convertion to list